# Where has $> gone ?

Tags: ruby, predefined-variables

[This](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/review.jsp?rid=777943) is one of solution to [this problem](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=0013).

```
a=[];$<.map{|l|l=='0'?($><<a.pop):a<<l}
```

I run it on a terminal but it displays no output.

Where has `$>` which is $DEFAULT_OUTPUT gone?

I used `p $>` etc but it does not output the result.

How can I display the result of `$>` on a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`$>` works fine, the problem is elsewhere.

```
irb> $><<:hello_world
hello_world=> #<IO:<STDOUT>>
```

The real culprit is `$<` (which is `ARGF`). When you run `$<.each { }` in the terminal, there are no args for `ARGF` and it hangs waiting for them.

```
irb> $<.map { }
# hangs...
```

If you put this in a file and ran it with command line arguments, or piped in the arguments from something else, it would probably do what you expect.

If you replace `$<` with an array, it seems to work.

```
arr = ['0', '1', '2']
a=[];arr.map{|l|l=='0'?($><<a.pop):a<<l}
#=> [#<IO:<STDOUT>>, ["1", "2"], ["1", "2"]]
```